# Firebase Database Rules to Avoid Data Leakage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a chat application that uses firebase database to store chats and firebase storage to store images, videos etc (Authentication method is Phone & OTP). Here is the structure
[image: Structure]

Now considering from attacker point of view, we cannot hide or obfuscate the database URL in our code. Now if attacker gets the firebase database URL, he can simply do URL/.json to view database content. My question is what rule should I have in place to ensure that only authenticated user can view chats (of their own only).
Currently my database is read, write (true), which is incorrect
and firebase storage is

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the above one allows authenticated user to access complete firebase storage instead of his own particular images / videos etc.

Please suggest correct rules

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad a question to answer succinctly. You'll need to modify the security rules to allow only the exact operations that your application needs, something known as the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). So: set your rules to deny all reads/writes, then try to use the app. Check where it fails and change your rules to allow *only* that failure to now succeed. Repeat this until you find no more failures in your app.

Comment: I recommend reading about [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) in the Firebase documentation, and checking previous [questions about the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database%20firebase-security?sort=MostVotes)